# Python 3.5 MySQL Connector

Tags: python, mysql

I'm somewhat new to python and figured playing around with mySQL databases would be a good idea.

Now the error I am having is simply installing the mySQL connector. I have tried on both my Windows PC, and now here on my mac. 
Each time I download the connector and install it, all goes ahead and installs, yet when I import mysql.connector I receive a traceback, ImportError saying that mysql is not a package.

I've been searching the internet trying to find information or ways to help this, but non have been successful.

It should be noted that I have restarted my computer, still with no success.

I installed python 3.5 via the official python website, and the mysql connector via the official mysql website.

Comment: Can you describe in details what you did when trying to install?

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional Hi, I have updated the main post, and also went into a bit more detail to a reply below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide more information. Could tell us how you installed the connector? easy_install? pip? Are you on Python2 or Python3. On windows are you using the official Python installer or did you install Python via Cygwin?

Typically, after you install a Python package, you'll find it in the following location on Mac/Linux:

```
 /usr/lib/python<version>/site-packages/
```

On Windows you'll find site-packages under the Python directory in C:\Program Files.

Which MySQL connector have you installed (there are several)?

Also, ensure you've installed the connector for the correct Python version. If you're using Python2, but are using `pip3` to install the package, then `pip` will install it to the python3 site-packages and you won't be able to access it from Python2.

Comment: Afternoon, thanks for the speedy reply. I am currently on my mac, trying it from here. As far as I am aware, for Python 3.5 there was only 2 downloadable files for the connector, both seemed to be the same.

I have installed this connector, and also attempted to do so using sudo and pip. However, one intriguing thing I noticed, is it seemed to install at the following directory: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

I only have Python 3.5 installed on this computer.

Comment: You should be using pip. If I recall correctly, MacOS comes with python2. Be aware that not all MySQL libraries support Python3. According to https://python3wos.appspot.com/, PyMySQL does, but MySQL-python does not. Which module did you install?

Comment: The file name for the mysql connector?
mysql-connector-python-2.1.3-osx10.9

Comment: When i try and follow the pip instal/update instructions I also get a very big traceback error. Not sure how to post in a comment.

Comment: you probably have libraries or dependencies on your Mac for python2, so when you try to install it is defaulting to version python2 of the connector rather than python3 version...you need to fully remove any trace of python2 and try to reinstall  the mysql.connector module for python that is compatible with python3+...

Comment: I don't think @JBond4546 needs to remove Python2 entirely! (It's installed by default on Mac and used a lot internally!!). They two can exist side-by-side fine. JBond, you can edit your original question with more details. Please add your backtrack to your original question in a code block. Do NOT uninstall Python2 from your Mac.

Comment: @djsumdog Too late xD already uninstalled it.
The problem I seem to be having now, is just setting the path of installs to use python 3.5

Comment: Don't worry. Managed to get it working.
It seems my computer was running pip2 instead of pip3.